# How to query HBase based on two columns' ranges?

Tags: java, database, hbase, nosql

I have a HBase table with a schema like this:

row key, col1, col2, col3

I want to query the table based on the ranges on two columns, like:

1000 < row key < 1000000 AND
200 < co1 < 300

How can I do that? I have noticed that Java API provides the MultiRowRangeFilter which can filter only one column, but I want to filter two columns based on the range. Anybody has some thoughts? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to query by 1 rowkey and 1 column, not 2 columns. Don't you?

Comment: Yes, I want to query by 1 rowkey and 1 another column. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When querying by 1 row key range and 1 column range, `MultiRowRangeFilter` doesn't apply since it is to filter **multiple** row key ranges, such as

```
100 < rowKey < 200 AND 1500 < rowKey < 2000
```

You want to use a `Scan` on row key with a `FilterList` of 2 `SingleColumnValueFilter`.

```
byte[] keyStart = Bytes.toBytes(1000);
byte[] keyEnd  = Bytes.toBytes(1000000);
byte[] columnMin = Bytes.toBytes(200);
byte[] columnMax = Bytes.toBytes(300);
byte[] cf = Bytes.toBytes(familyName)
byte[] column = Bytes.toBytes(columnNameToBeFiltered)

Scan scan = new Scan(keyStart, keyEnd);
FilterList list = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);

SingleColumnValueFilter filter1 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
cf, column, CompareOp.GREATER, columnMin);
list.add(filter1);

SingleColumnValueFilter filter2 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
cf, column, CompareOp.LESS, columnMax);
list.add(filter2);
scan.setFilter(list);
ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
...//parsing result
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Do the two parameters provided in Scan() are performing query on row key? Do I have to explicitly specify the row key? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I'm using hbase-client version 1.2.4. It provides `Scan(byte[] startRow, byte[] stopRow)` constructor. You don't have to specify anything else. Should have a look at API doc https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#Scan-byte:A-byte:A-